# React axios edit text on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm very new to frontend development, I'm trying to create a simple app which contains Posts and Comments linked to each post. How do I allow the edit (aka show a text field of an already created post) when its corresponding edit button is clicked? I have no idea what i'm doing in any of this edit code

```html
const Post = ({
  postId,
  content,
  authorId,
  authorName,
  timestamp, 
  isEdited, 
  comments,
  userId,
  userRole,
  getAllPosts
}) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
  const [commentContent, setCommentContent] = useState('');
  const [editedPostContent, setEditedPostContent] = useState('');

  const handleCreateComment = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(backend+"/post/comment/"+postId, {
        commentMsg: commentContent
      }, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
      const { message } = response.data;
      if (message) {
        console.log(message);
        setCommentContent('');
        getAllPosts();
      } else {
        console.log("CreateComment Error");
      } 
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("There are something wrong about create comment :(");
    }
  };

  const onTextFiledPressEnter = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      handleCreateComment();
    }
  };

  const handleEditPost = async () => {
    try{
      const response = await axios.patch(backend+"/post", {
          postId: postId,
          message: editedPostContent
        },{
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
      const { message } = response.data;
      if(message){
        console.log(message);
        setEditedPostContent('hello edited post');
        getAllPosts();
      }else{
        console.log("Edit Post Error");

      }
    }catch(e){
      console.log("There is something wrong about edit post");
    }
  };

  const handleDeletePost = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.delete(backend+"/post/"+postId, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
      const { message } = response.data;
      if (message) {
        console.log(message);
        getAllPosts();
      } else {
        console.log("DeletePost Error");
      } 
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("There are something wrong about delete post :(");
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.header}>
        <div className={classes.user}>
          <img 
            className={classes.img}
            src={UserImg}
          />
          <div className={classes.userDetail}>
            <div className={classes.owner}>{authorName}</div>
            <Moment className={classes.time} fromNow>{timestamp}</Moment>
          </div>
        </div>
        { (userRole === ROLE.ADMIN || userId === authorId) &&
          <div>
            <EditIcon 
              className={classes.icon}
              onClick={() =>
                handleEditPost()
              }
            />
            <DeleteIcon 
              className={classes.icon} 
              onClick={(e) => 
                handleDeletePost()
              }
            />
          </div>
        }
      </div>
      <div>{content}</div>
      { isEdited && <div>
        <div className={classes.edited}> Edited 
        </div></div>


      }
      <Divider className={classes.divider}/>
      { comments.map((comment) => (
        <Comment
          key={comment._id}
          postId={postId}
          postAuthor={authorId}
          commentId={comment._id} 
          content={comment.commentMsg}
          isEdited={comment.isEdited}
          timestamp={comment.timestamp}
          commentAuthor={comment.userId}
          commentAuthorName={comment.username}
          userId={userId}
          userRole={userRole}
          getAllPosts={getAllPosts}
        />
      ))}
      <TextField
        placeholder="Write a comment..."
        variant="outlined"
        size="small"
        value={commentContent}
        onChange={e => setCommentContent(e.target.value)}
        onKeyDown={onTextFiledPressEnter}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Accept postId as an input parameter for handleEditPost function. Something like that:

```
const handleEditPost = async (postId) => {
....
}
```

Then invoke handleEditPost in jsx :

```
  <EditIcon 
              className={classes.icon}
              onClick={() =>
                handleEditPost(post.id)
              }
  />
```